# Luminoth requires a TensorFlow >= 1.5 installation (Windows 8.1)

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

When ran a command

```
G:\luminoth>lumi -h
```

Getting error message

```
Luminoth requires a TensorFlow >= 1.5 installation.

Depending on your use case, you should install either `tensorflow` or
`tensorflow-gpu` packages manually or via PyPI.
```

Although When i check the tensorflow module detail it shows

```
G:\luminoth>pip show tensorflow
Name: tensorflow
Version: 1.9.0
Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: opensource@google.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: g:\python36\lib\site-packages
Requires: wheel, numpy, tensorboard, astor, protobuf, absl-py, six, termcolor, s
etuptools, gast, grpcio
Required-by:
```

Is there any thing to do ?

Comment: try to import tensorflow inside a python shell, it will probably fail. You have to fix that.

Comment: Yes it is failing when i import it and unable to find solution for it

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error. I am using tensorflow 1.14
Then tried to import tensorflow in python shell. It gave the error 'ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found'.
To resolve this install protobuf 3.6.0 `pip install protobuf==3.6.0`. This should solve the issue.